# How to define this paritcular typescirpt type

Tags: typescript, types

I have this static property as a part of my abstract class, with a number of properties, `default` is only consistent property, all the rest could have random names

```
  public static data = {
    default: { //only this one always have 'dafault' name
      name: 'someName',
      category: ['cat 1','cat2','catN'],
      urls: ['url1', 'url2']
    },
    property1: { //can have any random name 'property3' 'xyz'
      name: 'property1',
      category: ['cat 3','cat4','cat1'],
      urls: ['url3', 'url5']
    },
    anotherThing: { //can have any random name 'oneMoreThing' 'abc'
      name: 'anotherThing',
      category: ['cat 2','catN','cat5'],
      urls: ['url5', 'url2']
    }
  };
```

I want to strict type that property to get a better error validation. I wonder how would you define that structure in typescript interface?

Comment: You mean strict type that some properties should have defined values like category can be in array of values or just the type array string etc ..

Comment: @RebaiAhmed yeah, I am a bit confused because some props names are not consistent...

Comment: So make it easy and make a normal model containing arrays and strings

Comment: I don't understand, is the name of the property in `data` supposed to match its `name` property?  If so, why does that not happen with `default`?  Is `default`'s `name` property supposed to be one of the other key names?  There might be a way to represent your type as a generic, but it's hard for me to understand what your actual requirement is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to have the same name for a property as well as for its `name` subproperty's value, I don't think that's possible...

However, if you only wish to have any name for the properties, it is quite simple:

```
type MyType = {
  default: {
    name: string;
    category: string[];
    urls: string[]
  }
  [key: string]: {
    name: string;
    category: string[];
    urls: string[];
  }
};
```

You could add a subtype for better readability or if its structure is used somewhere else:

```
type MySubType = {
  name: string;
  category: string[];
  urls: string[];
};

type MyType = {
  default: MySubType;
  [key: string]: MySubType;
};
```